# How to fix Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert deserialize failure?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net WebAPI app. I'm returning files to the client in the Request.CreateResponse(,) second parameter as type `Dictionary<string, List<System.Net.Http.StreamContent>>`, where `List<System.Net.Http.StreamContent>>` contains all the files.

I'm deserializing the files at the client using the following:

```
var someContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<System.Net.Http.StreamContent>>>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

This code throws the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newstonsoft.Json.dll.
>
> Additional information: Unable to find a construction to use for type
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent. A class should either have  default
>   constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked
>   with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'myFiles[0].Headers'

Is there a different way to return actual files?

Comment: That seems an odd choice to me. Any reason you're not just returning a `Dictionary<string, List<byte[]>>` instead?

Comment: That seems to work well. Thanks.

Comment: `List<byte[]>` only gets me the actual file without the name. If I want the name, should I do `Dictionary<string, List<byte[]>>`?

Comment: Well yes, that's what I suggested. Or potentially just a `Dictionary<string, byte[]>`. Or a `List<FileContent>` where `FileContent` is a type with `Name` and `Content` properties (`string` and `byte[]` respectively). We don't really have enough information about what you're trying to do...

Comment: Is `FileContent` a custom class? If so, then what is `Content` on that class?

Comment: Yes, it's a class you'd write - and the type of `Content` would be `byte[]`, as I said in the previous comment. It would be the contents of the file.